# "Потяг" і "поїзд": чи є різниця і яке краще вживати?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, синоніми, іменники, семантика

Неодноразово була свідком суперечок щодо того, яке слово правильно вживати: "потяг" чи "поїзд".

Набагато частіше можна почути "поїзд", але також панує думка, що "потяг" є власне українським, в той час як інше запозичене з російської.

У поезії зустрічаємо:

Володимира Сосюри:

> "Коли **потяг** у даль загуркоче,
>
> Пригадаються знову мені
>
> Дзвін гітари у місячні ночі,
>
> Поцілунки й жоржини сумні…"

У [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%97%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83) ці слова подані як синоніми:

> **По́їзд**, також **по́тяг** — у залізничному транспорті, сформований і
>   зчеплений склад вагонів з одним або декількома діючими локомотивами чи
>   моторними вагонами, що мають встановлені сигнали.

Академічний словник української мови дає тлумачення слова "[поїзд](http://sum.in.ua/s/pojizd)", яке схоже до зазначеного вище. А от жодне з тлумачень до слова "[потяг](http://sum.in.ua/s/potjagh)" не відповідає значенню одиниці залізничного транспорту.

*То яке з слів правильно вживати на позначення одиниці залізничного транспорту та чи є між ними різниця, якщо допускаються обидва?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Офіційний сайт Української мови](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/slovnik_sinonimiv/p/potjag/38-1-0-12989) подає слова потяг і поїзд як синонімні:

> Синоніми до слова ***ПОТЯГ***: (швидкий) ***поїзд***; (до чого) прагнення, нахил, покликання, пристрасть, прив'язання, смак, у фр. УПОДОБАННЯ; (до кого) поваб, ваба; (статевий) ХІТЬ.

[Словник синонімів української мови, 2014](http://synonyms_uk.enacademic.com/6059/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B3) мітить таку статтю:

> **Потяг**
>
> I (**низка з'єднаних між собою залізничних ваґонів**); ешелон (потяг певного призначення з людьми й вантажем), ***поїзд***.
>
> II див. бажання 2), покликання, прагнення.

[Словарь української мови за ред Б. Грінченка](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B3) теж подає статтю, в якій помітно, що ці 2 слова є синонімними:

> **Потяг**, гу, м.
>
> 1) Влеченіе, побужденіе, стремленіе. У його потяг до танців та до скоків. Рк. Левиц.
>
> 2) Доходъ, прибыль. Нема потягу. Н. Вол. у.
>
> 3) ***Поѣздъ.***
>
> 4) Ремень у сапожниковъ, которымъ придерживается сапогъ или доска на колѣняхъ. Вас. 161.
>
> 5) Длинная и узкая полоса бураковъ или иного посѣва, далеко потянувшаяся въ поле. Рк. Левиц.
>
> 6) мн. Потягиваніе. Потяги напали мене. Н. Вол. у. (Лобод.).

В [Українському правописі](http://pravopys.mova.info/pravopys.aspx?SectionID=298) у §19 щодо спрощення груп приголосних наводиться слово поїзд:

> **Поїзд** — поїзний.

Щодо [Академічного тлумачного словника (1970—1980)](http://sum.in.ua/s/potjagh) або, по-іншому, СУМу-11, то там є стаття, в якій пише:

> **ПО́ТЯГ** 2, а, чол., заст., поет. ***Поїзд*** (у 1 знач.).

Отже, висновок: слова *потяг* та *поїзд* є синонімними.